# How to plot the orbit which spirals into centre of orbit by using loops?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hi i have written some codes when i try to plot the orbit,b=beta=3,G=1, i cant get the orbit which spirals into the centre by using loops it shows an incomplete orbit.
below  is the code with b=beta=3 and G=1 :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def dbydt(t,v):
    x,y,vx,vy=v
    rsq=x**2+y**2
    G=1
    b=3
    beta=3
    return vx,vy,-G*x/rsq**((b+1)/2),-G*y/rsq**((beta+1)/2)
result=solve_ivp(dbydt,[0,2],[1,0,0,1],t_eval=np.linspace(0,2,100))
plt.scatter(result.y[0],result.y[1])
plt.scatter(0,0,color='yellow',s=200)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you increase your final time to more than `2`, eg. `25` in this case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def dbydt(t,v):
    x,y,vx,vy=v
    rsq=x**2+y**2
    G=1
    b=3
    beta=3
    return vx,vy,-G*x/rsq**((b+1)/2),-G*y/rsq**((beta+1)/2)

t_final = 25
result=solve_ivp(dbydt,[0,t_final],[1,0,0,1],t_eval=np.linspace(0,t_final,512))
plt.scatter(result.y[0],result.y[1])
plt.scatter(0,0,color='yellow',s=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]